# Wait for Delegate callback to finish the function in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a 3rd-party SDK where architecture is like this:

- I call a method of the service (lets call it `TheirService`)
- Once that method completes, a delegate of that service (lets call it `TheirServiceDelegate` will receive a notification `onSuccess` if call succeeds or `onFailure` if it fails.

The problem with that is that methods of `TheirService` are dependant on each other, so I end up having a "chain reaction", where each next method of `TheirService` is called from previous callback.

Note that `TheirService` is single threaded, and is really picky about previous method to be complete before I can start the next one.

Currently my interactions with the service look like this:

```
protocol MyClientListener { 
    notifyOnFailure()
    notifyOnResult(result: SomeObject)
}

class MyClient: TheirServiceDelegate {

    static let instance = MyClient()

    let myService = TheirService()
    var myResult: SomeObject?
    var resultListener: MyClientListener

    private init() { }

    func start(resultListener: MyClientListener) {
        self.resultListener = resultListener
        myService.initialize()
    }

    // TheirServiceDelegate method
    func onInitializeSuccess() {
        myService.bootstrap()
    }

    // TheirServiceDelegate method
    func onBootstrapSuccess() {
        myService.login(user, password)
    }

    // TheirServiceDelegate method
    func onLoginSuccess() {
        myService.doSomethingUsefulStep1()
    }

    // TheirServiceDelegate method
    func onDoSomethingUsefulStep1Success() {
        myService.doSomethingUsefulStep2()
    }

    // TheirServiceDelegate method
    func onDoSomethingUsefulStep2Success(result: SomeObject) {
        // ah, look, now I have some object I actually wanted!
        resultListener.notifyOnResult(result)
    }
}
```

I also have to deal with failure case for each of them. And I cannot skip or change the order of steps, which creates some sort of awkward state machine.

Instead i would like to interact with service via logical functions, that complete certain stages of the process from end to end, waiting for results between the steps:

```
 class MyClient {

    static let instance = MyClient()

    let myService = MyService()

    private init() { }

    func connect() throws {
        myService.initialize()
        // wait for success or failure, throw on failure
        myService.bootstrap()
        // wait for success or failure, throw on failure
        myService.login(user, password)
        // wait for success or failure, throw on failure
    }

    func doSomethingUseful() -> SomeObject {
        myService.doSomethingUsefulStep1()
        // wait for success or failure, throw on failure
        myService.doSomethingUsefulStep2()
        // wait for success or failure, throw on failure
        // on success, it will get an object it could return
    }
```

Called like this:

```
try MyClient.instance.connect()
let x = try MyClient.instance.doSomethingUseful()
```

So is there any way to turn "wait for success or failure" comment into actual code that waits for that single-threaded service to call back? And where a delegate would fit in that case?

Comment: What is the `TheirService`? Like link to their files on GitHub?

Comment: @impression7vx it's not open source, can't provide a link or their source code (I don't have it, all I have is their API which I access via POD, and instructions how to use it, which result in this chain)